# Shopware 6 plugin- How to limit StorefrontRenderSubscriber scope to listing and search pages

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I am developing a Shopware 6 plugin that handles pagination. In my plugin, I have a `StorefrontRenderSubscriber` which passes some data to the TWIG templates:

```php
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Storefront\Event\StorefrontRenderEvent;
use Swag\SwagPagination\TComponents\SwagPaginationData;
use Swag\SwagPagination\Components\Helper\LoggerHelper;
use Swag\SwagPagination\Service\ConfigService;

class StorefrontRenderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    protected const EXTENSION_NAME = "SwagPagination";

    protected ConfigService $configService;
    protected LoggerHelper $loggerHelper;    

    public function __construct(ConfigService $configService, LoggerHelper $loggerHelper) {
        $this->configService = $configService;
        $this->loggerHelper = $loggerHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Get subscribed events for this subscriber.
     *
     * @return array The list of subscribed events and their associated methods
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
            StorefrontRenderEvent::class => 'onStorefrontRender'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Callback method for the storefront render event.
     *
     * @param StorefrontRenderEvent $event The event object
     * @return void
     */
    public function onStorefrontRender(StorefrontRenderEvent $event): void {
        try {
            // Retrieve the current request
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            // Retrieve all query parameters
            $queryParameters = $request->query->all();

            // Create an instance of SwagPaginationData
            $pluginData = new SwagPaginationData();

            // Get the configuration and check if it's active, add queryParameters
            $config = $this->configService->getConfig();
            if ($config && $config->isActive()) {
                $pluginData->assign([
                    'active' => $config->isActive(),
                    'queryParameters' => $queryParameters,
                    /*
                     * add more fields here
                     */
                ]);
            }

            // Add the extension to the context
            $event->getContext()->addExtension(self::EXTENSION_NAME, $pluginData);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Log any exceptions
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e);            
        }
    }
}
```

This subscriber currently runs on every page. However, I got feedback from the Shopware review team that it should be limited to only run on listing and search pages where pagination is needed.

How can I update my subscriber to limit its scope and only run on the listing and search?

Comment: I cannot fully answer this question as I am not familiar with shopware, but maybe I can help a bit. Did you check for other shopware events ? Maybe some are specific to the listing and search actions so they may be more suited for your event subscriber ? Or maybe use the `Request $request` to check the current page and wheter or not to apply your pagination.

Comment: If you are not sure wheter or not there are events that would help you, you may try to find it yourself by looking into the code, the docs, or using the profiler to check which event are fired when going on your list/search page (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/event/finding-events#using-the-symfony-profiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugin data can be passed to product listing and search pages by calling their respective events such as `ProductListingResultEvent` and `ProductSearchResultEvent`.

```php
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductListingResultEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductSearchResultEvent;

class ProductListingSearchSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    protected const EXTENSION_NAME = "swagPagination";

    protected ConfigService $configService;
    protected LoggerHelper $loggerHelper;    

    public function __construct(ConfigService $configService, LoggerHelper $loggerHelper) {
        $this->configService = $configService;
        $this->loggerHelper = $loggerHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Get subscribed events for this subscriber.
     *
     * @return array The list of subscribed events and their associated methods
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
             ProductListingResultEvent::class => 'onProductListingResult',
             ProductSearchResultEvent::class => 'onProductSearchResult',
        ];
    }
    
     /**
     * Callback method for the product listing result event.
     *
     * @param ProductListingResultEvent $event The event object
     * @return void
     */
    public function onProductListingResult(ProductListingResultEvent $event): void {
        try {
            // Retrieve the current request
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            // Retrieve all query parameters
            $queryParameters = $request->query->all();

            // Create an instance of SwagPaginationData
            $pluginData = new SwagPaginationData();

            // Get the configuration and check if it's active, add queryParameters
            $config = $this->configService->getConfig();
            if ($config && $config->isActive()) {
                $pluginData->assign([
                    'active' => $config->isActive(),
                    'queryParameters' => $queryParameters,
                    /*
                     * add more fields here
                     */
                ]);
            }

            // Add the extension to the context
            $event->getContext()->addExtension(self::EXTENSION_NAME, $pluginData);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Log any exceptions
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e);            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback method for the product search result event.
     *
     * @param ProductSearchResultEvent $event The event object
     * @return void
     */
    public function onProductSearchResult(ProductSearchResultEvent $event): void {
        try {
            // Retrieve the current request
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            // Retrieve all query parameters
            $queryParameters = $request->query->all();

            // Create an instance of SwagPaginationData
            $pluginData = new SwagPaginationData();

            // Get the configuration and check if it's active, add queryParameters
            $config = $this->configService->getConfig();
            if ($config && $config->isActive()) {
                $pluginData->assign([
                    'active' => $config->isActive(),
                    'queryParameters' => $queryParameters,
                    /*
                     * add more fields here
                     */
                ]);
            }

            // Add the extension to the context
            $event->getContext()->addExtension(self::EXTENSION_NAME, $pluginData);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Log any exceptions
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e);            
        }
    }
}
```